# Lacquer. Perfect Round Holes. Wood Glue. Etc

Tags: finishing, staining, box-joint, jigsaw

I'm a hobbyist.
I'm building a guitar cab.

This is my first touch of a table saw and first try and box joints.

A couple of Q's:
1. I sanded the heck outta this thing but apparently not enough to get the leftover glue. I stained this and obviously it didn't stain over the glue. Bummer. So some parts of the cab have "blemishes". Do I just need to sand MORE next time? How do I ensure a great stain?

2. I cut the center hole out with a jigsaw and it's not perfect.  It's not bad but it's not perfect. How would I get a better result?
3. How do I get a REALLY nice glossy shine and protection on this? I used about 4 coats of spray polyurethane lacquer ... and while its an ok finish, I'm looking for a protective coating but also a really smooth and glossy finish.  How do I achieve that?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Cab Pict 1]

[image: Cab Pict 2]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  We usually handle one topic per question here and I would suggest that you edit this question and ask the second part as a separate question (the sanding and finish questions relate well) to get good responses for each subject.  Thanks.

Comment: Since this is your very first time using a table saw please allow me to issue a caution. Table saws are the single most dangerous piece of equipment in a woodworking shop and great care should be exercised when using one, *every time*. Pros have often become complacent about the danger and don't demonstrate appropriate safety measures when they use theirs...... e.g. virtually all North American woodworkers on YouTube! So without realising it you may have picked up a number of, ah, questionable habits already.

Comment: *"Do I just need to sand MORE next time?"* If you were using solid wood, yes. But you can't sand much more using plywood as you run the risk of sanding through the surface veneer. (If using solid wood you might start sanding below 60 grit, assuming you weren't using a plane or scraping.) So with ply you might be temped to use less glue to limit the amount of squeeze-out but that's not really a good idea, the 'secret' is to clean it up more carefully after the clamps are tightened while the glue is still liquid.

Comment: Re. your 2, you just need to make and use a circle-cutting jig. Re. 3, you don't need to ask this as a new Question, we have numerous previous Q&As that touch on the subject.... like this, https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/a-beginners-question-about-sanding-stain-and-polyurethane-for-a-smooth-finish/8146#8146 ;-)